# How to combine React default styles with a style prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following ui-component:

```
...
import stylePropType from 'react-style-proptype';

const Heading = ({
  ...
  marginBottom,
  strong
}) => (
  <Header
    style={{
      marginBottom,
      fontWeight: strong ? 'bold' : 'normal',
    }}
  >....
  </Header>
);

Heading.defaultProps = {
  children: <div />,
  marginBottom: 4,
  strong: false,
  style: {},
};

Heading.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  marginBottom: PropTypes.number,
  strong: PropTypes.bool,
  style: stylePropType,
};
```

How can I combine the current style logic (marginBottom and fontWeight) with optionally additional styles passed in as a prop? Is there a way to combine the two or merge them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the spread syntax (`...`) on your passed in styles:

```
  <Header
    style={{
      marginBottom,
      fontWeight: strong ? 'bold' : 'normal',
      ...this.props.style
    }}
  >....
  </Header>
```